# Change SOAP message content programmatically with C#

Tags: c#, soap

I have the soap request message which is in myrequest.xml file and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <get_waybill_by_number xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <su>UserName</su>
      <sp>Password</sp>
      <waybill_number>Number</waybill_number>
    </get_waybill_by_number>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to write specific userName, password and waybill Number in the corresponding places. I have tried to achieve this task using several classes and methods such as XmlDocument, XmlNode, XmlNamespaceManager but I even can't get the data:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\D\desktop\myrequest.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);


xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("Soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("temp", "http://tempuri.org/");



XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//Soap:body/temp:get_waybill_by_number",xmlNamespaceManager);

foreach (var item in nodeList)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need it this case to add 'Soap' namespace. Try this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\D\desktop\myrequest.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);

xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("temp", "http://tempuri.org/");

XmlNode xmlNode = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//temp:su",xmlNamespaceManager);
xmlNode.InnerText = "myUserName";
xmlDocument.Save(@"C:\Users\D\desktop\myrequest.xml");
Console.WriteLine(xmlNode.InnerText);
```

After executing this code, "myUserName" will be written in your file instead of "UserName". You can do the same on Password and Number values